# Is there a term for the ratio of a function and its derivative?

Tags: terminology

Given a function $f(x)$ and its derivative $f'(x)$, is there a term for $\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$ or for $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$?

Comment: Not sure if this is the kind of thing you're after, but the latter is referred to in finance as the "interest rate" :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop based on the answer, does the *interest rate* have something relate to the logarithm function?

Comment: @Ooker: not exactly by definition, but yes it does. Consider an exponential function $f(x) = e^{Ax}$, then the "interest rate" is $A$, it controls how steeply the curve climbs. And $log(f(x)) = Ax$, lo and behold, has derivative $A$. It also turns out (by the chain rule), that the result holds in general (quoted by muaddib), not just for the exponential function.

Comment: The intuition here is that the logarithm "turns multiplication into addition". Therefore the rate at which the logarithm is increasing, is the rate at which the function is multiplying, i.e. the rate of compound interest. Add to the logarithm of the function = multiply the function. Sort of thing.

Comment: In economics, the latter is closely related to the [Arrow-Pratt measure of absolute risk aversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_aversion#Absolute_risk_aversion) of a utility function: $A(x;f)=-\frac{f''(x)}{f'(x)}$; if we take @muaddib's notation and modify it slightly, we get the (equivalent analog to the) [Arrow-Pratt-De Finetti measure of relative risk aversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_aversion#Relative_risk_aversion): $\frac{d\log(f(x))}{d\log(x)}=\frac{xf'(x)}{f(x)}$, while $R(x;f)=-\frac{xf''(x)}{f'(x)}$

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Certainly the latter one is called the logarithmic derivative:
$$\frac{d\log(f(x))}{dx} = \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$$

Comment: The first part doesn't hold if$f(x)\leq 0$.

Comment: Thanks - this is actually how I got this ratio in the first place.

Comment: I first encountered this surprise with integral(1/x) = log(x), a special case of this relation it turns out.

Comment: @metacompactness it does if you use the standard branch $\ln(-1)=i\pi$

Comment: @k_g Sure if $f:\Bbb{C}\to \Bbb{C}$ but it doesn't hold if $f:\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}$